# Go back to old color after storyboard color animation in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid where the row color is decided by a level parameter that I convert in my rowstyle. This is fine but now I also want to change the color temporarily when I enter the row with my mouse and drag and drop (and change back when I leave or drop). I manage to change the color with this code:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDataGridRowStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Level,Converter={StaticResource LevelToIndentConverter}}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGridRow.DragEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="DragHoverStoryboard">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                Duration="0:0:0" To="#41B1E1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGridRow.DragLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                Duration="0:0:0" To="Transparent" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The problem is to get back to the orginal color. Currently I have "To" as transparent in the DragLeave event trigger but I want it to be my "old" color.

I tried to do a simple bind (same as my setter) but I got exception and read that you can't bind color animations. So is there something else I can use or get around this problem? In summary I simply want this:

1. Mouse enter row with drag and drop
2. Row change to color x
3. Mouse leave row (or I drop)
4. Row change back to it's color y (where y is different for different rows so not hard coded).

Answer (score 0):

then add this to property to your animation and remove the second animation

```
FillBehavior="Stop"
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I forgot/was a bit  unclear. This is when I do drag and drop and then I think I have to to do EventTriggers? If not that solution would have worked. I updated the question to make it a bit more obvious.